# How to specify where an edge connects to a node in Graphviz

Tags: python, graphviz, pygraphviz

I am trying to use Graphviz to create a family tree but the diagram that is created comes out kind of wonky. To clean up the diagram I tried to specify the `headport`, `tailport` and `edge` length for some of the connections but it doesn't look like its working.

Here is an image of my attempt to create a family tree with the names whited out. As you can see  some of the edges and nodes are in the wrong place.
[image]
Here is my code where I try to specify the `edge` length, `headport` and `tailport` for the spousal relationships:

```py
if len(this_gen) > 0:
    for j in range(0, len(this_gen)):
        # note x creates a dot in-between the couple that is used as a connection point for their kids
        with dot.subgraph() as subs:
            subs.attr(rank='same')
            subs.node(per1, per1, tooltip=det, shape=sh, fillcolor="black")
            node_nm.append(per1)
            subs.node(per2, per2, tooltip=det, shape=sh, fillcolor="black", tailport="e", headport="w")
            subs.node(x, x, tooltip=det, shape='point', fillcolor="black", tailport="e", headport="w")
            subs.edge(per1, x, arrowhead='none', color="black:invis:black",len="1", tailport="e", headport="w")
            subs.edge(x, per2, arrowhead='none', color="black:invis:black",len="1", tailport="e", headport="w")
            df.loc[df['prof_names'] == this_gen['prof_names'].iloc[j], 'recorded_ind'] = 1
```

Comment: It appears you are using "splines=ortho" very reasonable, but "ortho" can produce wonky results.  Try "splines=false" or "splines=polyline".

Comment: ok thanks! "splines=false" came out a lot cleaner than "splines=ortho"